# How can I create an icon to exectue a custom gnome-terminal command?

Tags: command-line, scripts, gnome-terminal, .desktop

I want an icon, which I can double click to execute a terminal command.
So far I've created an executable script:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal -e cd ~/gPodder/Downloads/M4As\ To\ Be\ Converted/ && for f in *.m4a; do avconv -i "$f" "${f/%m4a/wav}"; done && for i in *.wav; do opusenc --bitrate 26 --downmix-mono "$i" "${i/%wav/opus}"; done && find . -type f -iname \*.wav -delete
```

Since I've just thrown things together kind of arbitrarily I'm not surprised it doesn't work, so what do I have to change in order for it to open a new terminal window executing the specified sequence of commands?

The actual command (starting from `cd` to `-delete`) actually works when manually entered in a terminal window.

Comment: Unfortunately both of those tries ways didn't work for me. I get "There was an error starting the application".

I don't want to call on any script, I just want the above command to be executed in the terminal. Shouldn't there be a simple way to do this?

Comment: I've created a .desktop file:

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=cd ~/gPodder/Downloads/M4As\ To\ Be\ Converted/ && for f in *.m4a; do avconv -i "$f" "${f/%m4a/wav}"; done && for i in *.wav; do opusenc --bitrate 26 --downmix-mono "$i" "${i/%wav/opus}"; done && find . -type f -iname \*.wav -delete
Name=ConvertM4AsToOpusMono26kbps

But: There was an error starting the application...

Comment: Failed to execute child process "cd" (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 3):

Use a .desktop file to call the script, put this in a text file and save it with the extension `.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My script
Comment=Runs my script
Exec=
Icon=
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

On the `exec` line you can put the path of your script, same for an icon.

You then make this file executable with `chmod +X` or by right click and go to permissions.

You can add this to the launcher or any location you like and click it to run the script.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a launcher that will execute your command on your desktop
2. move launcher to `/usr/share/applications`
3. set read and execute permissions on launcher file so that every user can access and execute it.

Detailed answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/68023/332981

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier if you create a separate script, let's say `~/bin/foobar`, starting with the proper "shebang" line (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`), give it executable permissions, and then ask gnome-terminal to run this script, i.e. `gnome-terminal -e foobar`.

If you really need to inline the complex command line, start with this proof of concept:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "cd somewhere; ls; sleep 10"'
```

and if you can confirm that it works then replace the innermost command line with whatever you'd prefer there, replacing `"` by `\"` everywhere.

Comment: your test line works, but as soon as I replace it by the  cd ~/gPodder/Downloads/M4As\ To\ Be\ Converted/ part. A terminal window is opened and closed immidiately. Same after replacing " by \" as you suggested.

Comment: You're right that I did not test it, your example is quite complex to work out of the box, and I didn't feel like coming up with something similarly complex. Try converting the backslash characters to double backslash, and/or swapping the single and double quites in my example.

Comment: It's even simpler to use '-x' or '--' rather than '-e', it goes something like: `gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'cd somewhere; ls; sleep 10; whatever...'`